# PHP - How can I append/merge onto an array with depth

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a database query which returns several records, however I would like to append more data to this object by typing the array as an object so that I can for example add more data to the output than the database contains.

I have done some research on this and found some functions such as array_merge but whenever I attempt to use this it gave me issues related to the array's depth and sometimes even created an entirely new array key instead of adding onto the currently existing ones.

This is the data from my database:

```
Array
(
    [Cat] => Array
        (
        )

    [Dog] => Array
        (
        )

    [Rabbit] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => fluffy
                    [owner] => foobar
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => toby
                    [owner] => foobar
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => josie
                    [owner] => Joseph
                )

        )

)
```

I'd like to make it so that every array key which exist have an extra field but other animals remain empty if they do not have any records.

Example:

```
Array
(
    [Cat] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => ralph
                    [owner] => Joseph
                    [extra] => some extra data
                )
        )

    [Dog] => Array
        (
        )

    [Rabbit] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => fluffy
                    [owner] => foobar
                    [extra] => some extra data
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => toby
                    [owner] => foobar
                    [extra] => some extra data
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => josie
                    [owner] => Joseph
                    [extra] => some extra data
                )

        )

)
```

The reason I am attempting to merge the two is because I have several helper functions which generate pretty results and I'd like to utilize them rather than output the raw data from the database, the extra data is demonstration of how i'd like to merge onto the current array.

Thanks!

EDIT - Updated code:

```
function listPets(){

    $foo = [];
    foreach($pets as $p){

        $getPets = $database->Findall("SELECT name, owner, info FROM pets...");
        $foo[$p->name] = $getPets;

        foreach($foo as $arr){
            if(count($arr)){
                foreach($arr as $v){
                    $v->extra = $this->message($getPets->info);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return $foo;

}
```

Comment: array_merge_recursive() ?

Comment: When I used this it seemed to create a new key [2] rather than add to all current keys [0], [1], not sure why

Comment: @mhvvzmak1, show the "extra data" array which should be merged with the initial array

Comment: I have updated my question with current code I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

- Loop through the array using `foreach` loop.
- Check if the inner array is empty or not.
- If the inner array is not empty then loop through it and append `extra` property to each of the objects.

So your code should be like this:

```
// Suppose $array is your original array
foreach($array as $arr){
    if(count($arr)){  // check if the array is empty or not
        foreach($arr as $v){
            $v->extra = 'some extra value'; // append extra property to the object
        }
    }
}

// display $array
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Here's the demo:**

- [Live Demo](https://eval.in/567090)

Comment: I got an error: Attempt to assign property of non-object

Comment: @mhvvzmak1 May be the array structure is different than what is presented in the question. You can see the demo by yourself. Are you sure about the array structure?

Comment: I will update my question with the new edits I have made using your solution which gives me this error

Comment: @mhvvzmak1 *hmm, strange*. Try to test your application with this code snippet, [http://pastebin.com/NQWj7Lfv](http://pastebin.com/NQWj7Lfv). It's quite the same, except that it converts object into array, merge it with another array and then convert it back to `stdClass` object.

Comment: I will try this version, I have also just updated my question so you can see the code which returned the error

Comment: This version seems to give me the error too, not sure what it is but it only happens if I set the extra value to a returned object of my database query.

Comment: @mhvvzmak1 Few suspicious things in your code. 1) In iteration of `foreach` loop you're executing a query. 2) With `$getPets` you're getting the result set, so this statement `$getPets->info` is wrong. 3) Do `var_dump($v);` inside inner `foreach` loop and check whether it's an object or not. Also do `var_dump($pets);`, paste it's output on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: The reason I'm executing a query inside the foreach is because I have select multiple sets of data, e.g. WHERE location = foo,bar. $getPets->info should return the correct value as all other queried values are accessible this way. I'll look into the var_dump shortly and leave a reply.

Comment: So i added another foreach inside this solution which is foreach as the query returns many rows of pets ($getPets as $pe) and then set the array value, however this gives all of the pet types the same name which it shouldn't

Comment: @mhvvzmak1 I don't think that will do any good. `$getPets` is the mysqli resultset returned from the [`query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) method. So you have to do `while($pe = $getPets->fetch_array()){ ... }` to loop through it. RTM, [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: Noo the database variable is a call to my own database class function which returns all rows from the database automatically for me

Comment: @mhvvzmak1 You've given us very little information to work with. Without knowing anything's structure, it's difficult to help you. Do `var_dump($pets);` and `var_dump($getPets);`, paste their outputs on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and give me their links here.

Comment: Hi I have modified your solution so that now it works for my use case, not sure if it is the most efficient way to merge them but it works now

Answer (score 0):

The function below merges arrays & objects:

### UPDATE

```
<?
    function fuse_data()
    {
        $list = func_get_args();
        $data = array_shift($list);
        $type = gettype($data);

        $data = ((array)$data);

        foreach ($list as $indx => $item)
        {
            foreach ($item as $name => $valu)
            {
                if (!isset($data[$name]) || empty($data[$name]))
                {
                    $data[$name] = $valu;
                }
            }
        }

        return (($type == 'object') ? ((object)$data) : $data);
    }
?>
```

Use it like this:

```
    $data = fuse_data($result, $node2, $list3, $foo, $bar);
```

Edit as you like, it's just a proof of concept.

Comment: I will try this solution, can I ask how to call it using my variables?

Comment: @mhvvzmak1 :: sure!  once you have the data in your variables from running your queries, you can fuse them all together -either into a new variable, or into one of the result variables you have.  I've updated the answer for you, look at the bottom..  Basically its just:  `$fused_result = fuse_data($result_1, $result_2, $an_array, $or_object);`  .. any number of arguments you like, it will all cram into 1 without overwriting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually trying to merge two arrays or just append some extra information to the non-empty keys in the array of animals?

In the second case, depending on the information you want to add, there's two ways you could go:

1. Add it to the SELECT statement:

   ```
   SELECT name, owner, 'extra stuff' as extra FROM ...
   ```
2. Do it like @rajdeep-paul said. Only you can skip the empty array check, if it's empty, foreach will not iterate through it anyway:

   ```
   foreach ($dbData as $animals) {
       foreach ($animals as $animal) {
        $animal->extra = 'extra stuff'; 
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like ...

```
foreach($pets as &$pet) { // passing by reference to manipulate the original array.
 if(!empty($pet) && is_array($pet)){ // Checking if the element is an array and not empty 
  foreach($pet as &$feature){ // Again passing by reference the 2nd dimension
   if(is_object($feature)){ // Checking if the element is object to prevent the "Property of non-object" error.
    $feature->extra = 'Some value'; //  If all is well, we asign the new property to the object.
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Now even though I think there are better ways to write(optimize) a query than firing it inside a loop!!! but just for the sake of your question, your code should be like..

```
function listPets(){

    $foo = [];
    foreach($pets as $p){

        $getPets = $database->Findall("SELECT name, owner, info FROM pets...");
        $foo[$p->name] = $getPets;

        foreach($foo as $arr){
            if(is_array($arr) && count($arr)){
                foreach($arr as $v){
                    if(!empty($v) && is_object($v)){
                      $v->extra = $this->message($getPets->info);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    return $foo;

}
```

Comment: Getting the same issue as Rajdeep Paul's answer, I think it's because the $getPets is a call to return all rows rather than one

Comment: whats the error? there are various errors that you have discussed over his answer, so what is the exact error?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object at this line $v->extra = $this->message($getPets->info);, probably on $getPets as $getPets returns multiple records and therefore it is unable to loop without being in the $arr loop but then it breaks other stuff such as the info field only returns the first pet's information, not all of the pets.